# Detect a direction of uislider thumb drag in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uislider, drag

I need to disable dragging thumb of UISlider to right direction and enable its dragging to left. How can I do it in Swift 3?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From where your slider starts? Extreme right?

Comment: From extreme left

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain an "old value" so that you can compare it to the "new value" and then simply set it back.

```
class ViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    var value: Float = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        value = slider.value
    }

    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider, forEvent event: UIEvent) {

        if sender.value > self.value {
            sender.setValue(self.value, animated: false)
        } else {
            self.value = slider.value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your old value and set initial value as you need:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    var lastValue:Float = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lastValue = slider.value

    }

    @IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        if sender.value > lastValue {
            slider.setValue(lastValue, animated: false)
        }
        lastValue = sender.value
    }
}
```